# Webpack: ReferenceError: requrie is not defined

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babel-loader

I am trying to set up a simple react project with webpack and babel here. Ran into problem when I first build.

webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = requrie('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './src/main.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: 'main.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js?$/,
                exclude: /mode_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'env']
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    target: 'web'
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "main-script",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "react": "^16.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.0",
    "webpack": "^4.4.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.13",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.1"
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
C:\main-script\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\webpack.js:242
                                throw err;
                                ^

ReferenceError: requrie is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\main-script\webpack.config.js:2:14)
    at Module._compile (C:\main-script\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:178:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (C:\main-script\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at WEBPACK_OPTIONS (C:\main-script\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\convert-argv.js:133:13)
    at requireConfig (C:\main-script\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\convert-argv.js:135:6)
    at C:\main-script\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\convert-argv.js:142:17
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports (C:\main-script\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\convert-argv.js:140:15)
    at yargs.parse (C:\main-script\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\webpack.js:239:39)
    at Object.parse (C:\main-script\node_modules\webpack-cli\node_modules\yargs\yargs.js:543:18)
    at C:\main-script\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\webpack.js:217:8
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\main-script\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\webpack.js:512:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\main-script\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js:80:2)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! main-script@1.0.0 build: `webpack`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

I have searched the web seeing people meeting similar error. They usually solve it by adding adding `target:'web'` , which is the default. I made sure I have added that already but I still had no luck.

Any reason why that is so?

Comment: replace `requrie` with `require`

Comment: Oh damn... Stupid typo.... But thank you. Real savior!